# Python Tkinter only drawing in first interation of a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, tkinter, drawing

I am trying to make a GUI for an othello game that i made in Python. The for loops below only display pieces in the first row. Once it iterates through the nested for loop a second time, no more pieces are displayed on any of the next rows. What is preventing these other pieces from being drawn?

```
def _draw_pieces(self) -> None:

    self._canvas.delete(tkinter.ALL)

    rows = int(self._width/RADIUS)
    columns = int(self._height/RADIUS)

    x_frac = 0
    y_frac = 0

    for row in self._board:
        for column in row:
            if column == NONE:
                self._draw_neutral_piece((x_frac/rows),(y_frac/columns))
                x_frac += 1
            elif column == BLACK:
                self._draw_black_piece((x_frac/rows),(y_frac/columns))
                x_frac += 1
            elif column == WHITE:
                self._draw_white_piece((x_frac/rows),(y_frac/columns))
                x_frac += 1
            else:
                x_frac = 0
        y_frac+= 1
```

The functions _draw_black_piece, _draw_white_piece, etc. are all basically written the same. They take a fractional coordinate and draw a piece of that color. The coordinates are determined by the size of the board after it is resized. The default size of the board is the number of pieces in each column and row times the RADIUS constant, which is set to 100.

```
def _draw_black_piece(self, x_frac: float, y_frac: float) -> None:

    x_radius = self._canvas.winfo_width()/len(self._board[0])
    y_radius = self._canvas.winfo_height()/len(self._board)

    x1 = self._canvas.winfo_width() * x_frac
    x2 = self._canvas.winfo_width() * x_frac + x_radius
    y1 = self._canvas.winfo_height() * y_frac
    y2 = self._canvas.winfo_height() * y_frac + y_radius

    self._canvas.create_oval(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill = 'black')
```

Here is the the board as well:

self._board = [[NONE,BLACK,NONE,WHITE],[NONE,BLACK,WHITE,NONE],[NONE,WHITE,BLACK,NONE] [NONE,NONE,NONE,NONE]]

Comment: Are you certain it's only drawing one row, or is it possible it's drawing all rows but drawing them all in the exact same spot? Have you taken the simple step of printing out the coordinates of each piece to see if the coordinates are what you're expecting them to be?

Comment: Yeah, i tried printing out the coordinates, and they were all correct. I even tried iterating through different slices of the list and it still only displayed in one row, although a different row.

Comment: That can't be true. If the coordinates are correct, Tkinter absolutely will draw the object at those coordinates. I recommend you create the smallest possible _complete_ program to duplicate this. Focus on drawing all pieces the same color so you're not trying to debug three nearly identical functions at the same time.